# Eventbrite and Drupal

Tags: drupal, eventbrite

How do I embed a list of events into the page.tpl.php?

This is my current code:

```
<?php include "eventbrite.php";

$authentication_tokens = array('app_key' => '************',
                                'user_key' => '**************');
$eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens );

<?= Eventbrite::eventList( $resp, 'eventListRow'); ?>
```

But this is not returning any results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Eventbrite](https://www.drupal.org/project/eventbrite) and [Eventbrite API](https://www.drupal.org/project/eventbrite_api) modules of Drupal.

```
These module provides tight integration with the Eventbrite platform using the Eventbrite API.
```

In other way Eventbrite also provide widgets code to embed directory on the site. You can get the widget from Eventbrite site and display the list of events anywhere on the site using Drupal blocks.

Comment: Unfortunately my client wants me to use their hosting company whose setting will not let these module scripts run as they are too long (a lot of events to import and I get 504 timeout error when importing :o(  ). I have asked for it to be increased, but no luck. Stuck up a creek with no paddle!? So I am looking to write the php code myself so it only imports what I need.

Comment: The Eventbrite module doesn't actually create a list of events for my site. The 'deep integration' is a bit too deep for me! Also, when I try to use the Eventbrite widget on my site, if fouls up, a) taking me to a 'non-drupal' page and b) that page looks awful!